# Django Internal Server 500 Error AWS Elastic-Beanstalk issue

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

How do I fix the Django Internal Server 500 error on an AWS eb deployed application?

Do I need to change my allowed hosts in my **base.py** file to have the ip address of the ec2 in elasticbeanstalk?

```
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
# Raises ImproperlyConfigured exception if SECRET_KEY not in os.environ
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django_admin_bootstrapped',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

...

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

...

I enabled DEBUG and ran eb config, and eb logs. The **eb deploy** values are displayed below, and the **eb logs** values below that. How do you fix the issue that the "No module named django?"

```
    Creating application version archive "app-3e17-161020_112522".
Uploading pronet/app-3e17-161020_112522.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
INFO: New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
INFO: Environment update completed successfully.
```

Provided below are the output from eb logs.

```
============= i-0b11de8b8521ea5c0 ==============
-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
[Thu Oct 20 17:46:59.414032 2016] [:error] [pid 11268] 
[remote 172.31.5.67:41390] Traceback (most recent call last):

[Thu Oct 20 17:46:59.414077 2016] [:error] [pid 11268] 
[remote 172.31.5.67:41390]   File "/opt/python/current/app/pronet/src/pronet/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>

[Thu Oct 20 17:46:59.414083 2016] [:error] [pid 11268] 
[remote 172.31.5.67:41390]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

[Thu Oct 20 17:46:59.414104 2016] [:error] [pid 11268] 
[remote 172.31.5.67:41390] ImportError: No module named 'django'

[Thu Oct 20 17:47:00.046644 2016] [:error] [pid 11268] 
[remote 172.31.5.67:43182] mod_wsgi (pid=11268): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/pronet/src/pronet/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.

[Thu Oct 20 17:47:00.046704 2016] [:error] [pid 11268] 
[remote 172.31.5.67:43182] mod_wsgi (pid=11268): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/pronet/src/pronet/wsgi.py'.

[Thu Oct 20 17:47:00.046738 2016] [:error] [pid 11268] 
[remote 172.31.5.67:43182] Traceback (most recent call last):

[Thu Oct 20 17:47:00.046784 2016] [:error] [pid 11268] 
[remote 172.31.5.67:43182]   File "/opt/python/current/app/pronet/src/pronet/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>

[Thu Oct 20 17:47:00.046789 2016] [:error] [pid 11268] 
[remote 172.31.5.67:43182]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

[Thu Oct 20 17:47:00.046810 2016] [:error] [pid 11268] 
[remote 172.31.5.67:43182] ImportError: No module named 'django'

[Thu Oct 20 17:47:01.340552 2016] [:error] [pid 11268] 
[remote 172.31.5.67:43182] mod_wsgi (pid=11268): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/pronet/src/pronet/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.

[Thu Oct 20 17:47:01.340603 2016] [:error] [pid 11268] 
[remote 172.31.5.67:43182] mod_wsgi (pid=11268): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/pronet/src/pronet/wsgi.py'.

[Thu Oct 20 17:47:01.340653 2016] [:error] [pid 11268] [remote 172.31.5.67:43182] Traceback (most recent call last):

[Thu Oct 20 17:47:01.340701 2016] [:error] [pid 11268] 
[remote 172.31.5.67:43182]   File "/opt/python/current/app/pronet/src/pronet/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>

[Thu Oct 20 17:47:01.340706 2016] [:error] [pid 11268] 
[remote 172.31.5.67:43182]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

[Thu Oct 20 17:47:01.340728 2016] [:error] [pid 11268] 
[remote 172.31.5.67:43182] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

link to github project. You can view all the code here

https://github.com/IantheFlyingHawaiian/Pronet

Comment: do you have debug enabled in `settings.py`? If so, what is the traceback there?

Comment: enable `DEBUG` to see the error in console

Comment: I enabled the debug, but I'm still getting the same "django module not found error." Any ideas why?

Comment: 2022 guy here: I resolved by setting the SECRET_KEY env from EB environment-> Configuration-> Software->Environment properties

Answer (score 5):

Did you do this?

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

If you didn't, AWS will not know that it should [install Django and other dependencies on your EC2 instances for your deployment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html).

Answer (score 2):

In my case error with *sqllite*

Remove Database settings from *settings.py* and try deploy

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

And then I configured with AWS RDS.

Comment: This was the case for me too. The OS sqlite version was too low for the adapter I was using..

Comment: so you deleted the whole `DATABASES` object from settings.py?

Comment: Nope. Just change it like above. the engine and path as mentioned above.